# Request.pipe() JPEG streams

Tags: node.js, mjpeg, nodejs-stream

I'm working on a nodejs app that works as a middleware for ZoneMinder. In short, my goal is to mask all ZoneMinder api so that the client doesn't know if I'm using ZM or not.

Everything work fine, but there is one thing that bugs me. There is a streaming api in ZM that gives a streaming JPEG (MJPEG) and you can put that in an `img` tag. Right now I'm using `pipe()` to pipe this stream to the client. Something like this:

```
app.get('/stream', async (req, res) => {
    let url = 'do stuff here to get ZM url'
    request(url).pipe(res);
})
```

This works. What I'm curious about is how exactly this `pipe()` going to affect performance on my machine. Note that I'm running both ZM and the nodejs app on the same machine. Will the `pipe()` make my system effectively bear double the load of the stream? Is there a better solution than this, given the desired outcome?

Comment: Data comes in, and data goes out.  That's about it.  Probably some buffering, but it's pretty lightweight.  You don't really need Node.js for this though... looks like any normal proxy server would do, if this is what your code does.

Comment: @Brad I have a few more things I need to process too, this is just 1 function of the app. But thanks